# How to proceed with finding memory leaks after pulling dominator tree and pathToGCRoth reports

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I've done with developing my app, now I'm trying to find bugs. First thing I've noticed is constant memory increase in GC_FOR_ALLOC message which starts from cca 9.000k and goes to 50.000k as I scroll listView.

I'm still a novice, so my first stop was developer documentation but as I pulled these reports I'm pretty stuck as I really don't know how to proceed when I discovered what is causing memory leak. Any advice and help is appreciated.

[image: Path to GC root]

[image: Dominator tree]